# Not able to Resolve PolicyMangar and Metadata in Android

Tags: java, android

I am new in android development. I am try to build an custom player in android.
I am googling and find some code and try to build it everything is going good but i am not able to resolve PolicyManager (com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager) & MetaData (android.media.Metadata) Class. I am also search about these class but not find any solution. I am still not resolve this. please help me how to resolve this problem

Code:- (Problem in Metadata Class)

```
Metadata data = MediaPlayerInternals.getMetadata(mp, false, false);


            if (data != null) {
                mCanPause = !data.has(Metadata.PAUSE_AVAILABLE)
                        || data.getBoolean(Metadata.PAUSE_AVAILABLE);
                mCanSeekBack = !data.has(Metadata.SEEK_BACKWARD_AVAILABLE)
                        || data.getBoolean(Metadata.SEEK_BACKWARD_AVAILABLE);
                mCanSeekForward = !data.has(Metadata.SEEK_FORWARD_AVAILABLE)
                        || data.getBoolean(Metadata.SEEK_FORWARD_AVAILABLE);
            } else {
                mCanPause = mCanSeekForward = mCanSeekForward = true;
            }
```

Code:- (Problem in PolicyManager Class)

```
mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is PolicyManager or DevicePolicyManager ?

Comment: Hi hulk, i am sure it PolicyManager

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/PolicyManager.java.shtml here is your policy manager class

Comment: Hulk, I am used this class but this is not a solution. bcs this class have some dependance